# Importing CSV database with null character as empty strings

Tags: mysql, csv, mysql-workbench

I have hundreds of csv files and each one have lots of null characters in it. It is like that because the some of the cells must be empty. But when I try to import this into MySQL workbench using import wizard i keep getting the same error: "Unhandled exception: line contains NULL byte".

What I would like to do was to:

a) be able to import these database without the error from above

b) converting all null cells as empty strings.

Since there are hundreds of csv files like this one, each around 300mb, replacing the characters before importing doesn't seems to be a quick viable option.

Is there a way to force MySQL Workbench to accept the files with the null character in it?

I have googled many answers, none of which seems to be applicable to this case.

Many thanks

Comment: The only option I see is the one you mention: delete the null character from these files using some sort of script/program. It's slow and ugly, but shouldn't be too bad (computers are pretty fast these days).

Comment: @barrycarter that's what i was afraid :/
I tried doing it with python, but it would took forever to do it with all the files.

Comment: If you have more than 300M memory (actually, you may need 600M to hold two copies temporarily), you could copy the file to a RAM disk (or load it into memory), strip the nulls, write it back and copy it to hard drive again. I don't have any benchmarks but it really shouldn't be that bad. NOTE: it might actually be quicker to replace the NULL character with something-- that way, not even the file length changes.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Check this MySQL Workbench snapshot]

Since MySQL Workbench version 8.0.16 (released on 04/25/2019) there has been an additional option for uploading .csv file -- "null and NULL word as SQL keyword".

When selecting this option as **`NO`**, the NULL expression without quotes in .csv file (,NULL, rather than ,"NULL",) will auto-fill empty if your field default value is empty.

I hope this answer could solve other people's similar problem :)